# Замена скобки с буквой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
Самочувствие сегодня (конечно)плохое
```

Заменить на

```
Самочувствие сегодня (конечно) плохое
```

Comment: Отвечающие на этом сайте ставят минусы и закрывают вопросы, если они напоминают ТЗ. Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос [**собственными попытками**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) справиться с заданием. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте позиции слева и справа от скобок с помощью прямых и обратных опережающих просмотров:

```
$str = 'Самочувствие сегодня(конечно)плохое';

echo preg_replace('~(?<=\))(?=\S)|(?<=\S)(?=\()~', ' ', $str);
```

Результат:

```
Самочувствие сегодня (конечно) плохое
                    ^ пробелы ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Двумя заменами: первая для закрывающей скобки, вторая - для открывающей:

```
$str = 'Самочувствие сегодня (конечно)плохое(да)очень';
$str = preg_replace('~(\))(\S)~', '$1 $2', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~(\S)(\()~', '$1 $2', $str);
echo $str;
// Самочувствие сегодня (конечно) плохое (да) очень
```